# Spark job hanging with 0 executors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a problem with Spark's dynamic allocation policy.

Occasionally, when a node in the cluster dies, the executor on that box is the last remaining executor for more than 60 seconds (heartbeat timeout is 5 minutes).  As a result, the ExecutorAllocationManager removes all other executors.  Finally, the last executor times out, leaving the job with zero executors.  The ExecutorAllocationManager does not request anymore.

Relevant spark settings:

```
spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles     true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled      true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled    true
```

I have been able to resolve this problem by setting spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors to a value greater than the number of executors remaining on the dead cluster node, but I am not super happy with that solution.

Comment: How many nodes do you have in the cluster? More specifically does the cluster have enough resources to allocate when a node goes down or is it a very busy cluster?

Comment: It happens on our busy 100 node cluster, but I am able to easily reproduce this on our 8 node development cluster where it is the only job running.  

Currently on Spark 2.2, but it looks like Spark 2.3 is able to recover from the same situation after about a fifteen-minute stall.